# Pagination not working when replacing Table by Dynamic DataTable in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, datatables

I am generating a Dynamic table based on user's search result with those searched columns only.
The table is generated in AJAX page and coming back as response in another page.The pagination alone is not working.
please help.
My Code:

```
<?php
require_once('../Connections/finalkms.php'); 
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);


$qry = " SELECT AssetId,";
$qry .= $data; 
$qry .= " from Completedetails";

mysql_select_db($database_finalkms, $finalkms);
$query_getcolumns = $qry;
$getcolumns = mysql_query($query_getcolumns, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getcolumns = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcolumns);
$totalRows_getcolumns = mysql_num_rows($getcolumns);

if (($getcolumns)||(mysql_errno == 0))  
{  
  echo "<table width='50%' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' align='center' id='sample_2'>
  <thead><tr id='vstr'>";  
  if (mysql_num_rows($getcolumns)>0)  
  {  

          $i = 0;  
          while ($i < mysql_num_fields($getcolumns))  
          {  
       echo "<th align='center'>". mysql_field_name($getcolumns, $i) . "</th>";  
       $i++;  
    }  
    echo "</tr></thead>";  

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($getcolumns,MYSQL_ASSOC))  
    {  
      echo "<tbody><tr>";  
      foreach ($rows as $data)  
      {  
        echo "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td>";  
      }  
    }  
  }else{  
    echo "<tr><td colspan='" . ($i+1) . "'>No Results found!</td></tr></tr>";  
  }  
  echo "</tbody></table>";  
}else{  
  echo "Error in running query :". mysql_error();  
}  

  ?>

 Here's My Java script code:

     <script>

     $("#sample_2").dataTable();

     </script>
```

Comment: How is it not working? It generates an error?

Comment: ya it's working @Acelasi Eu.The problem is with <tbody> tags.It's in loop , so for every record separate <tbody> is generated .So pagination is not working.Now I removed <tbody> tags then it's working fine.

Comment: ok, you should post the solution as an answer for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
<?php
    require_once('../Connections/finalkms.php'); 
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);


    $qry = " SELECT AssetId,";
    $qry .= $data; 
    $qry .= " from Completedetails";

    mysql_select_db($database_finalkms, $finalkms);
    $query_getcolumns = $qry;
    $getcolumns = mysql_query($query_getcolumns, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_getcolumns = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcolumns);
    $totalRows_getcolumns = mysql_num_rows($getcolumns);

    if (($getcolumns)||(mysql_errno == 0))  
    {  
      echo "<table width='50%' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' align='center' id='sample_2'>
      <thead><tr id='vstr'>";  
      if (mysql_num_rows($getcolumns)>0)  
      {  

              $i = 0;  
              while ($i < mysql_num_fields($getcolumns))  
              {  
           echo "<th align='center'>". mysql_field_name($getcolumns, $i) . "</th>";  
           $i++;  
        }  
        echo "</tr></thead>";  

        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($getcolumns,MYSQL_ASSOC))  
        {  
          echo "<tr>";  //removed body tag here
          foreach ($rows as $data)  
          {  
            echo "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td>";  
          }  
        }  
      }else{  
        echo "<tr><td colspan='" . ($i+1) . "'>No Results found!</td></tr></tr>";  
      }  
      echo "</table>";  
    }else{  
      echo "Error in running query :". mysql_error();  
    }  

      ?>

     Here's My Java script code:

         <script>

         $("#sample_2").dataTable();

         </script>
```